# Make a Fragment's Lifecycle Mimic Another

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

**WHAT I HAVE**

I have a `Fragment` called `MainFragment`. This is added from my `MainActivity`. Within that `Fragment` in on its `onResume` method I add another `Fragment` called `SecondFragment` like so.

```
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        SecondFragment secondFragment = (SecondFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(SecondFragment.FRAG_TAG);

        if (secondFragment == null)
            secondFragment = SecondFragment.newInstance();

        FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(mContainer.getId(), secondFragment, SecondFragment.FRAG_TAG).commit();
}
```

I then remove it like so.

```
@Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        SecondFragment mhpf = (SecondFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag( SecondFragment.FRAG_TAG );
        if ( mhpf != null )
            fm.beginTransaction().remove( mhpf ).commit();
   }
```

**THE ISSUE**

This all works well and good but it doesn't fit in with the lifecycle of the `Fragment` when things like orientation changes happen or when the user goes home and then opens the application up again.

**WHY I'M DOING IT LIKE THIS AND NOT ADDING IT FROM THE ACTIVITY**

This is part of an `Android Library Module` so I want it self contained. The user just has to add the `MainFragment` and then the `SecondFragment` is handled entirely by the `MainFragment`.

**MY QUESTION**

Is there a way to get my `SecondFragment` to behave like a normal `Fragment` without having to add it and remove it from and `Activity`?

Comment: If the second fragment is dependent on the first fragment you should probably think about using nested fragments, especially if they're going to share their container.

Comment: IN case of
   FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

use getChildFragmentManager;

Comment: if u r using fragment inside fragment then

Comment: Could you clarify, "it doesn't fit in with the lifecycle of the Fragment"? The first fragment's life cycle is controlled by the Activity. The second is only controlled by the first's `onResume` and `onPause`. Why not make a callback to the activity, from which the first fragment can easily add and remove the second?

Comment: I don't want the Activity to know about my SecondFragment. Only the MainFragment should be added by the Activity. The rest needs to be handled by the MainFragment

Comment: @PradeepYaduvanshy or Luksprog please post an answer regarding child/nested fragments and I shall accept it. This is what helped me. Whoever answers first wins :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  `getActivity().getChildFragmentManager()`; in place of  `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();`
If you are using Fragment inside Fragment.